# Are there any pools or large miners running "child pays for parent" patch?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, transaction-selection, child-pays-for-parent

A feature available through [pull #1647](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/1647) gives the recipient of a transaction a method to help get a transaction to confirm.

This feature is called "child pays for parent", and what it means is that the recipient of a transaction can create a new transaction using funds from the unconfirmed transaction, but any fee paid would help get both transactions confirmed.

A scenario where this is useful is where a merchant requires that a transaction have three or six confirmations before the item will be shipped out, but the payment the customer made ended up being a low-priority transaction due to it including many Bitcoin "dust" inputs.  The merchant then creates a spend transaction using the funds received but pays a fee that will encourage miners to include both transactions.

Since this feature is not in the Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind client, only miner pools that have a custom client that includes this pull will consider the fee paid by any child transactions when determining if a transaction should get included into a block.

Are there any miner pools or large solo miners who are running with this feature?

Comment: "Replace by fee" is another method increasing the priority of a transaction, but in this instance it would be the sender who submits a later transaction with a greater fee.  No miners or pools have claimed that they have implemented this patch.  More info: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/what-is-replace-by-fee

Answer (score 6):

According to an offshoot reply in bitcoin-talk it appears that the only mention of this protocol comes from Luke-Jr on Github.  Another topic on bitcoin-talk mentioned that his pool, elegeius, implements this patch.

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=173169.0

On the eligius FAQ page http://eligius.st/~gateway/faq/following-applies-transactions-being-processed-our-blocks

It mentions specifically = Transaction processing/priority contracts are available (talk to Luke-Jr).