# What is replace-by-fee?

Tags: protocol, replace-by-fee, bip-125-replaceable

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=199947.0

Can anyone explain what replace-by-fee means?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[This thread explains it](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=179612.0).

It's a method that allows replacing an already transmitted transaction by transmitting another transaction with a higher fee. This only works on transactions before they are signed by miners (0-confirmations).

Comment: So basically it floods the mempool with multiple transactions that only differ by fee. It seems this creates more "noise" for miners than necessary.

Comment: @Geremia the miner's are economically incentivized to discard the lower fee transaction. It should add more load to the network but shouldn't increase the size of the mempool.

Comment: If the fee is so high that makes sense for someone to mine on old blocks, surely it would also work for 1+-confirmations?

Comment: Normally a miner will pick the one with the highest fee. Some explorers continue to show the older double spent even after the new one has been confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

After 6 years, Now I want to tell you what is Replace by Fee :)

This feature was proposed in BIP125 and implemented in Bitcoin Core 0.12.0.

In simple words, by enabling ([Replace By Fee](https://blog.coincodecap.com/what-is-replace-by-fee-in-bitcoin/)) RBF in a transaction, if a transaction doesn't get mined, it can be resent by the sender with a higher mining fee with keeping the input data of the UTXO(Unspent Transaction Output) same as before.