# My Blockchain Payment Has Been Unconfirmed For 3 Days Now Please Help

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

https://blockchain.info/tx/342ca53d9a5dea2f63e81be6c4e39b4b3c61d6dae8b69e7e71f8c802f61da415

That’s the link it has been unconfirmed for a long time now can anyone help me please.

Comment: How did you send it?  Which client?

Comment: Blockchain Regular

Comment: I can't find this client.  Do you see a "replace by fee" option in this client?  Can you share a link to download this client?

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace by fee to encourage miners to pick up your transaction.  This should be your next step.  See here for more info:

[What is replace-by-fee?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10733/what-is-replace-by-fee)

Also, here is a how to:
https://freedomnode.com/blog/75/how-to-fix-slow-bitcoin-transactions-with-replace-by-fee

This site can help recommend what you should use for your fee so that you can set your expectations of when a transaction will be confirmed:
https://bitcoinfees.earn.com/
Basically, the more you pay with a fee, the faster it will be confirmed.  The less you pay, the slower it will be confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

You skimped on the mining fee (only 96 sat/byte). The miners will pickup other higher paying transactions in preference to yours. As mentioned above it is possible to send another transaction through with a higher fee. This is called double spend.

The Core developers have engineered this problem by restricting the blocksize thereby throttling the number of transactions per second that bitcoin can process.